# Too much space above and below equation and graphic

Tags: spacing, equations, subfloats, setspace

My latex program is doing some weird stuff and I can't figure out what to do. At one place in my document the space above and below an equation and a figure is way too much. But later in the document, the spacing is normal again. I am not using anything like `\setlength{}`. I am just using text, figures and equations. What could cause this strange behaviour?

This is the part that results in problems:

```
Abbildung \ref{fig:Graph_Bsp_1} veranschaulicht die soeben genannten Begrifflichkeiten und Definitionen.

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.23\textwidth]{graphs/Graph_Bsp_1a.png}\label{fig:Graph_Bsp_1a}}\qquad\qquad
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.23\textwidth]{graphs/Graph_Bsp_1b.png}\label{fig:Graph_Bsp_1b}}\qquad\qquad
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.23\textwidth]{graphs/Graph_Bsp_1c.png}\label{fig:Graph_Bsp_1c}} 
    \caption[Kurzbeschreibung]{Beispiele für einfache und endliche Graphen: Bei Graph (a) handelt es sich um einen gerichteten Graph mit einer Schlinge am Knoten $1$. Graph (b) hingegen ist ungerichtet und darüber hinaus auch vollständig, da jeder Knoten mit jedem anderen Knoten benachbart ist. Graph (c) ist ebenfalls ungerichtet und stellt einen Teilgraph von Graph (b) dar. Mathematisch wird Graph (c) beschrieben durch die Mengen $V=\{1,2,3\}$ und $E=\{[1,3],[2,3]\}$.} \label{fig:Graph_Bsp_1}
\end{figure}

\begin{itemize}
\item \textbf{Definition 2:} Zwei Graphen $G(V,E)$ und $G'(V',E')$ heißen \textit{isomorph} zueinander, falls eine bijektive Abbildung $\phi: V \to V'$ existiert, so dass gilt:
\begin{equation}
[x,y] \in E \Leftrightarrow [\phi(x),\phi(y)] \in E'
\end{equation}
\end{itemize}


In anderen Worten bedeutet dies, dass zwei Graphen isomorph sind, falls sie sich nur in der Bezeichnung ihrer Knoten unterscheiden.
```

And this turns out this way. As you can see the space below and above both the equation and figure ist too much:

[image]

However, later in the document I have this part, which has exactly the same structure as above but the output is normal:

```
Ein Beispiel für den Durchmesser eines Graphen ist in Abbildung \ref{fig:Graph_Durchmesser} dargestellt.

\begin{figure}[H]
 \centering
   \includegraphics[width=.7\textwidth]{graphs/Graph_Durchmesser.png}
\caption[Durchmesser eines zusammenhängenden Graphen]{\label{fig:Graph_Durchmesser}Durchmesser eines zusammenhängenden Graphen: Die Knoten A und B im dargestellten Graph haben den Abstand $a(\text{A},\text{D}) = 8$, was der Länge des kürzesten Weges zwischen den beiden Knoten entspricht. Da die Knoten A und B am weitesten voneinander entfernt sind, hat auch der Durchmesser des Graphen den Wert $D(G) = 8$. }
\end{figure}

Everything is fine here

\begin{equation}
spacing is normal here
\end{equation}

\begin{itemize}
\item \textbf{Definition 5:} Ein Graph $G$ heißt \textit{bewertet}, falls allen Kanten $e = [x,y]$ von $G$ ein \textit{Gewicht} $w(x,y) \in \mathbb{R} $ zugeordnet ist. Für bewertete Graphen ist die Länge eines Weges oder einer Kantenfolge die Summe der Gewichte aller Kanten des Weges oder der Kantenfolge.
\end{itemize}
```

And here the output has a normal spacing below and above the figure and equation.

[image]

Comment: There is probably a large box at the start of the next page (such as a figure [H]) which won't fit on this page and anything with glue is expanding to fill the space.  Either use \raggedbottom or [ht] instead of [H].

Comment: Thank you! That was exactly the problem I had, using [ht] solved it.

Comment: also never leave a blank line before a display math environment such as `equation`

Comment: You would not be believe all the problems caused by [H] floats!